# Multiple forward pass in pytorch lightning

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I am very new to Lightning. I have a pytorch code and I want it convert it to lightning. If you have some time Please help me. I have converted most of the step, but the only problem I am facing is in my pytorch code I am doing multiple forwarded passes as shown in the last loop. I don't know how to imply this in pytorch lightning. Please help me with that.

```
import random
import time
import torch 
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class Made(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,m):
        super(Made,self).__init__()
        self.m=m
        self.neural_made1=nn.Linear(self.m, self.m)
        self.neural_made2=nn.Linear(self.m, self.m)
        self.neural_made3=nn.Linear(self.m, self.m)
        self.prelu1=nn.PReLU()# learnable activation function
        self.prelu2=nn.PReLU()
        self.sig=nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self,x):
        self.hidden1=self.prelu1(self.neural_made1(x))
        self.hidden2=self.prelu2(self.neural_made2(self.hidden1))
        self.final=self.sig(self.neural_made3(self.hidden2))
        return self.final


        dyn_var=256
        Net=pf.Made(dyn_var).to(dev)

        I_Par=torch.zeros((bs,dyn_var)).to(dev)
        for i in range(dyn_var):#Autoregressive property or multiple forward passes proportional to number of input variables
            rand=torch.rand(bs).to(dev)
            with torch.no_grad():
                Net_1=(Net(I_Par))#forward pass of the neural network
                I_Par[:,i]=torch.where(Net_1[:,i] > rand,-1,1)    
            assert not I_Par.requires_grad
        Net_2=(Net(I_Par))
```

I have tried to look all the documentation but couldn't find anything till now.